# Silverlight Listbox with variable height fitting to content

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, listbox, height

How do I configure the listbox in Silverlight to have variable height ?

Comment: Please add more description to your question

Answer (score 2):

And this is the answer: :)

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Which height are you referring to? The control itself? Or the items inside the ListBox?

If you are referring to the height of the control, by default it is set to "stretch" therefore it will expand to with respect to its parent:

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot" Height="500">
   <ListBox />
</Grid>
```

If you want the ListBox to expand without relating to its parent either:
set its VerticalAlignment="Top":

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot" Height="500">
   <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

or:

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot" Height="500">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" />
</Grid>
```

The grid will expand with respect to its contents no its parent. you can also use converters bound to a height property or set the height in the xaml's codebehind.

If you are talking about the contents of the ListBox, create an ItemTemplate. An ItemTemplate will dictate how each of the contents will be displayed.

You can also set the itemspanel, this will dictate how the list will be displayed.
You can use Stackpanel/WrapPanel.